# Heroku logs for Rails app gives `require': no such file to load -- psych (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I pushed a Rails 3.2 app to Heroku and I'm getting the following errors:

```
app[web.1]: [2013-02-06 07:39:44] ERROR SignalException: SIGTERM
app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:90:in `select'
heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
heroku[api]: Release v13 created by ashley@hybridgroup.com
heroku[api]: Deploy 1800efe by ashley@hybridgroup.com
heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 28816`app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/safe_yaml-0.6.3/lib/safe_yaml/psych_handler.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load --psych (LoadError)
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/engine.rb:11:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/engine.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/safe_yaml-0.6.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:59:in `<module:YAML>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin.rb:1:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/safe_yaml-0.6.3/lib/safe_yaml/psych_handler.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/safe_yaml-0.6.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/safe_yaml-0.6.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:59:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 27035`
app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/safe_yaml-0.6.3/lib/safe_yaml/psych_handler.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load --psych (LoadError)
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/safe_yaml-0.6.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:59:in `<module:YAML>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/safe_yaml-0.6.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/safe_yaml-0.6.3/lib/safe_yaml.rb:59:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/engine.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin.rb:1:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/safe_yaml-0.6.3/lib/safe_yaml/psych_handler.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin/engine.rb:11:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails_admin-0.4.4/lib/rails_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.0.pre.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from /app/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2013-02-06T18:16:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

I'm not sure why it's saying the gems are in Ruby 1.9.1 as when I put `ruby -v` into the command line, it says I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 and I only have that version of ruby installed. I'm using Windows if it matters. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your Gemfile have the psych gem as a dependency?

***e.g.***

```
gem "psych", "~> 1.3.4"
```

---

Heroku maintains a very particular stack.  From experimenting with one of my current Heroku apps, I discovered that I didn't have psych by default, either.

If psych were available, the following command would have returned `true`

`heroku run "ruby -e 'puts require \"psych\"'"`

Comment: Thanks SO much! That was indeed it. I added that to my Gemfile and then it worked.

Comment: Great to hear! Enjoy Heroku!